# How to run Jenkins Pipeline defined in a single repo navigating through folder?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

**Problem**: I have a one single repository where I have to walk through the repo to find a specific Jenkinsfile to run the pipeline. Note that I want to define the path to this Jenkinsfile explicity so I thought about having a `jenkinsfilePath.yml` in root directory of the repo, read the yaml, change directory and run Jenkinfile from the path. The folder structure is as follows:

```
testingSingleRepo

├── Jenkinsfile
├── feature_flagging
│   ├── Jenkinsfile
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── src
│   └── tests
└── jenkinsfilePath.yml
```

I am having issue running Jenkinsfile inside `feature_flagging` from the root Jenkinfile in testingSingleRepo. I was successful in changing directory to the folder feature_flagging by using `dir`.  After googling a lot with similar questions, I came across the function `build` but I could not make that work. **Any suggestions/solutions?**

Comment: You may try making a symbolic link in the root directory with `ln -s feature_flagging/Jenkinsfile Jenkinsfile.lnk` and defining `Jenkinsfile.lnk` in your job configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after looking around, I have decided to go with another approach. I have decided that I will have a master `Jenkinfile` in the root where I will have a generic pipeline setup. It will read the yaml file, change directory and execute shell scripts inside `Jenkins/` folder accordingly. The folder will consist of generic scripts that reflects to the root Jenkins pipeline such as `setup.sh`,`test.sh`, `deploy.sh` etc.  The folder structure will look something like below:

```sh
testingSingleRepo

├── Jenkinsfile
├── feature_flagging
│   ├── Jenkins/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── src
│   └── tests
└── jenkinsfilePath.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling a Jenkinsfile from a main pipeline, we can use load

```
load 'feature_flagging/Jenkinsfile'
```

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion but after trying out `load`, I get error saying that I can only run one pipeline at a time. I googled around and couldn't find a fix for that.